# Meaning of this phrase?

Tags: meaning, phrases

So a friend of mine uploaded a picture of hers with her husband.  In the picture, both of them were wearing glasses.  As I scrolled down the comments, I read someone's comment saying "made for each other". Below that comment she wrote "I bet, **its the sunglasses that give it away**".

I want to know what does this sentence mean, especially the part that "the sunglasses gave [something] away." I didn't get it.

Answer (score 2):

"Made for each other" is a standard term that implies a deity created two people who would become a perfect couple.

Without seeing the picture, I can't figure out entirely what the "it's the sunglasses that give it away" means, but it's probably using either *similarity* or *lack of similarity* in the glasses that the people are (or are not) wearing to make a humorous comparison. E.g., if they are wearing identical sunglasses, then they're "made for each other" and the matching sunglasses are a sign of that. (Or that they're both wearing sunglasses or something.) If they're not wearing sunglasses at all, or if one is and one isn't, then it's perhaps a slightly sarcastic comment about a sign that *doesn't exist* -- or that they're "made for each other" because they're so *different* from each other most of the time. (Note that some people think that "made for each other" is a creepy phrase, implying they don't have any decision in who their partner is.)

Comment: Oh right, i didnt notice if they were wearing similar sunglasses or not. Could you please tell me the actual phrase that is used here? I want to know its standard form.

Comment: The actual phrase of which? There's some form of "You look like you *were made for each other*," but the joking reply could take many forms. If it's the "gave it away" part, that's a term that means "this was the final clue." E.g., in a crime drama, the captured criminal says, "What gave me away?" And the detective says, "You knew which explosives took out the safe. No one else did."

Comment: Yes, "give it away" part. Okay so here in my example, they both look identical, so she said it must be the sunglasses that made them look so, right?

Comment: No, she's (probably) not saying that the sunglasses made them look identical. She's saying that the sunglasses *were the clue* that "gave it away" that they were "made for each other." (It *might* be a layered meaning -- that the sunglasses caused them to look more similar, which was the clue that gave away that they were "made for each other.")